# Find Facebook user from picture

Tags: facebook, facebook-profile

I have a picture of a friend however I've lost contact with them and can't find them by name. Is there a way to use this picture to find their Facebook profile?

Comment: I came across a project that does exactly what you want, but only for Russian popular social network Vkontakte. Here is a [link](https://birdinflight.com/ru/vdohnovenie/fotoproect/06042016-face-big-data.html) (in Russian, feel free to use an on-line translator) about an experiment during which a guy was taking pictures of random people and how he was able to find their accounts in the social network by using this service. _(I am not affiliated with any services or companies that could be listed in the article)_

Comment: Have you tried [TinEye](http://tineye.com/) or the alternatives from [this answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/92809/117311)? Which one did finally work for you?

Comment: looks like you are searching for a girl you just photographed..

Answer (score 12):

Have you tried Google Image search?

Facebook profile photos are public (for discoverable accounts). If they have used the photo relatively recently a reverse image search may be helpful.

From [Google Image Search](https://images.google.com), click the camera icon in the search bar ("search by image"), then choose the option to upload an image. (If you have a modern browser, you can also drag-and-drop an image file.)

Google will then use the image to find other images that either match exactly or come close.

There isn't a way within Facebook to use reverse image searches.

Comment: "_Facebook profile photos are public"_ Only if the user has chosen for them to be.

Comment: @Lightness: Not according to [Facebook Help](https://www.facebook.com/help/203805466323736). Among the items under "Information you share that is always public" is listed "current Profile photo". Also, in the [instructions for changing the profile photo](https://www.facebook.com/help/388305657884730/) it says _"Note: Your current profile picture is always public."_

Comment: The privacy setting is automatically "public" on ones current profile photo, yes — though not the Profile Photos album, so you can hide older profile photos) — but that only makes a difference if your profile is discoverable. Mine isn't: I can open an incognito tab and go directly to my profile by URL and get [effectively] 404'd. There is no way to reverse engineer my identity through my profile photo unless we have mutual friends (and this is quite by design), or I've commented on/liked some (public) post of yours.

Comment: @Lightness: I'll add some clarification.

Comment: I think this only works well if it's the same photo. It's not a facial recognition algorithm as far as I've used it. It's a great way to find the original photo someone on Facebook (or match.com or Twitter or whatever) stole to create their fake profile.

Comment: Here's an example of a fake profile and you can find the original image and name of the model via image search. https://m.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100011723889261

Answer (score 6):

There is no official way to do so.

But if you found that picture from web and have not changed the name that file, you can search the id of Facebook profile using the number given in photo file name.

For example: suppose you have downloaded that pic from web and it saved as *41480_10738811_7375_n.jpg*, so here the middle number i.e. *10738811* is the profile ID from a Facebook user's profile. At the end put the profile ID number you copied from the filename:
http://www.facebook.com/people/@/10738811

<sup>Source: [turbofuture](https://turbofuture.com/internet/Finding-a-Facebook-Profile-from-a-Picture).</sup>

<sup><sub>I personally have not tested this. You can give a try.</sub></sup>

Comment: I *may* be wrong, but pretty sure they've change the naming conventions of photos so this won't work.

Comment: @hd. _They_ means who?

Comment: "They" means Facebook.

Comment: I confirm, they changed this naming convention some years ago exactly to prevent this kind of actions (and similar).

Comment: @Federico Indeed they have. Please have a look at [this answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/92809/117311) from May 15th '16.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that the answer given by [serenesat](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/87130/serenesat) earlier does not apply any more.

There are other alternatives as well apart from using [AI E.](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/354/al-e) solution of [Google images](https://images.google.com/).
Keep in mind that you cannot upload an image at Google Images’ mobile site since there’s no option to upload an image. You can do search though with the help of some text.

---

You can **also** use other "***Reverse Image Search Engines***" such as:

- [TinEye](http://tineye.com/) (the first website ever to use [Image Recognition Technology](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/image-recognition), used to track down illegal use of copyrighted images as well)
- [Bing Image Match](https://www.bing.com/images), by (Microsoft)
- [Baidu](http://image.baidu.com/) (very popular in China)
- [Yandex](https://www.yandex.com/images/) (very popular in Russia)

Answer (score -1):

FindFace could do the trick, but I ignore if is still available

https://blog.kaspersky.com/findface-deanon/11921/

You should try.

Comment: Always essential content of of the link into answer. Link only answer is invalid here.